# How to circumvent BigQuery's 20 concurrent queries limitation?

Tags: google-bigquery

Wondering if anyone knows... or have ran into this.. there's a 20 concurrent queries limitation for BigQuery.

https://developers.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#queries

Is there a way to disable the limit? Our MapReduce tasks needs many concurrent queries in order to complete within a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Upgrade your plan? ;)

Comment: I know this is an old question but as of writing this, the limit is now [50 concurrent queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy).

Answer (score 2):

We have a similar problem. There is no way how to change this from your side. Also "upgrading your plan" as @Dominik suggest won't help.

You have to contact Google directly, explain your problem (business case) and if it is valid they can increase your quota limits (for certain Google Cloud project)

Comment: It looks to me like reserved capacity pricing is the only option left for them.